# AutoCAD Command -DWGUNITS missing prompts

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, autocad

I have many custom AutoLISP commands that have been used for years within our company with no issues, until this morning.

We have an AutoLISP that runs the following:

```
(command "-dwgunits" 3 2 4 "no" "no" "no")
```

This is the beginning of one of our metric scale settings.
The issue we've been having today is the 3rd prompt for Scaling the drawing has stopped showing up on all of our desktops, which means the 3rd "no" is erroring out the rest of the command. I was able to get the command to prompt me for that 3rd item the first time i ran the command, and never again afterwards. I'm only recieving 2 prompts. Why is the 3rd prompt not showing up?

If i change the LISP to include only 2 "no"s, it starts asking for a 3rd. Strange behaviour...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering with AutoLISP, I was able to determine that if LUNITS was set to another value than what i wanted it to become, it would ask about scaling the items within the drawing. If i was running this command, and LUNITS was already the same, it would not ask about scaling objects in the drawing, which as how the arguments are delivered.

I was able to develop the following to do what i wanted:

Metric:

```
(if (= (getvar "LUNITS") 2) (command "-dwgunits" 3 2 4 "no" "no") (command "-dwgunits" 3 2 4 "no" "no" "no"))
```

Imperial:

```
(if (= (getvar "LUNITS") 4) (command "-dwgunits" 1 4 6 "no" "no") (command "-dwgunits" 3 2 4 "no" "no" "no"))
```